# Jquery Chosen focus on page load (onLoad?)

Tags: jquery, forms, onload

I'm using the Jquery Chosen plugin on a select box, however I'd like to focus this on page load. I've used the following code to focus a text input:

```
onLoad="document.forms.sales_order_form.customer.focus()"
```

But this doesn't work for the select box:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select a Customer..." class="chzn-select" name="customer" style="width:400px;">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 32):

In Chosen 1.0, this command is now:

```
$('.my_select_box').trigger('chosen:activate');
```

See [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html).

Answer (score 2):

If your using the first example (standard select box) you can use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.chzn-drop .chzn-search input[type="text"]').focus();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2">def</option>
    <option value="3">ghi</option>
</select>

...

      $("#myselect_chzn").children('.chzn-drop').children('.chzn-search').children('input[type="text"]').focus();
      $("#myselect_chzn").addClass('chzn-container-active');
```

Chosen creates owns divs and converts your "`select_ID`" into "`select_ID_chzn`" for those divs

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$("select.ProductIDDropDown").chosen();
$("select.ProductIDDropDown").trigger("liszt:activate");
```

or shorten it to

```
$("select.ProductIDDropDown").chosen().trigger("liszt:activate");
```

Comment: Worked for `Version 0.9.11`

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the issue completely for me:

```
$('.chzn-drop .chzn-search input[type="text"]').focus();
$('.chzn-container').addClass('chzn-container-active');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
jQuery("#fltrPerson_chzn a").addClass("chzn-single-with-drop");
                        jQuery(".chzn-drop").css({
                            "left": "0px",
                            "top": "24px"
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching into StackOverflow for this solution to use in one of my project. After searching a lot I have learned something but have got no proper solution. Finally I have fixed my problem as follows:

I am using `"jquery-1.10.2.min.js"` and `"Chosen v1.0.0"`. In my code I have `<select id="sel_product">` and in jquery `$("#sel_product").chosen()`. For adding focus I have added '_chosen' after my ID of the element and call the following function:

```
$('#sel_product_chosen a.chosen-single').focus();
```

My final code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sel_product").chosen();
    $('#sel_product_chosen a.chosen-single').focus();
});
```

Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post... but for what it's worth the following is an option as well...

```
  $('select').chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function () {
        //do something
    })
```