# jQuery focus not working with the plugin chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Chosen focus on page load (onLoad?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281627/jquery-chosen-focus-on-page-load-onload)

i am using a jQuery plugin chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to create more useful select boxes.

however, jQuery focus event is not working with this plugin.

my html code:

```
<select class="product">
<option value="1">Product One</option>
<option value="2">Product Two</option>
</select>
```

and javascript code:

```
$('.product').chosen().focus();
```

it is not focusing the element..

here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JigneshManek/queZ6/11/

is there any other method or event specified in the plugin to focus the element?

Answer (score 10):

This library looks nice, but it doesn't seem to let you interface with it beyond setting the initial parameters.

Still, try this:

```
$('.chzn-single').focus(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.chzn-single').focus();
});
```

What happens is the `$('.chzn-single')`, which is an `a` element, gets focused via tabbing, Chosen listens to that event and triggers the activation of the field and focuses the container. I needed to add `preventDefault` on click events in order to keep the focus on the container.

In any case, it seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

Following seems to work for me:

```
$('.chzn-container').mousedown();
```

Comment: -1: This does not just focus the element. It opens up the options in the element as well. It's not what focus would do on a select input.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that your original select box isn't there anymore, and has been replaced by a `<div>` and some `<ul>`s, so the standard browser behavior `focus` on an input control is no longer relevant.  You will need to look at the library, and see how to capture keydown events to create a virtual focus.  if you are lucky the library authors thought of this, and have provided some hooks for you.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is almost a year-old, but for someone who may need it:

to re-focus field after element from dropdown was selected I edited chosen source:
inside function *Chosen.prototype.choice_build = function(item) {* :
added

`this.container_mousedown();`

That is a dirty hack and partial solution to achieve re-focusing but it seems to be working for me on v.0.9.8 of plugin. If anyone can advise better solution - I will be glad to adopt it.