# focus event not working in chosen jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen jquery version 0.9.14.My problem is that chosen jquery does not supporting for focus event.Although i referred several example but that didnot help.
can anyone help me please.
i am using code as below:

```
    $('#proof_chzn').on('focus', function(e){
    var jobid=$('#id').val(); 
    if(jobid != ' ')
      {
          $("#proof").empty();
 jQuery.ajax({ 
      type: "post", 
      url:  "dynamicversion.php", 
      data: { id:jobid, flag:"refresh" }, 
      success: function(response)
      { 
                jQuery('#proof').append(response); 
              } 
        }); 
      }
     });
```

Html code for dropdown:

```
 <div id="proof_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" 
 style="width:   285px;" title=""><a tabindex="-1" class="chzn-single"  
 href="javascript:void(0)"><span>New Revision</span><div><b></b></div></a>
 <div class="chzn-drop"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text"   
 autocomplete="off">  
 </div><ul class="chzn-results"><li style="" class="active-result result-selected"  
 id="proof_chzn_o_0">New Revision</li></ul></div></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Chosen focus on page load (onLoad?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281627/jquery-chosen-focus-on-page-load-onload)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$(function() {
 $('#proof_chzn').trigger('chosen:activate');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching into StackOverflow for this solution to use in one of my project. After searching a lot I have learned something but have got no proper solution. Finally I fixed my problem as follows:

I am using `"jquery-1.10.2.min.js"` and `"Chosen v1.0.0"`.
In my code I have `<select id="sel_product">` and in jquery `$("#sel_product").chosen()`. For adding focus
I have added '_chosen' after my ID of the  element and call the following function:

```
$('#sel_product_chosen a.chosen-single').focus(function(){
    // rest of the code goes here
});
```

Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From the chosen [doco](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html):

> `chosen:showing_dropdown` -   Triggered when Chosen’s dropdown is opened.
>   
> `chosen:hiding_dropdown` -    Triggered when Chosen’s dropdown is closed.
>   
> `chosen:no_results` - Triggered when a search returns no matching results.

So for focus you could:

```
$(".selector").on("chosen:showing_dropdown", () => $(someTarget).trigger("focus"));
```

Answer (score -1):

AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML

Since you are using ajax, so you can change success part into:

> success: function(response)
>         {
>             callback(response);
>         }
>   });

You need a callback to  make the jQuery functional, for example:

> > function test() {
> >       testfunction(function(response))
> >     {
> >       jQuery('#proof').append(response);
> >     }
> >     }

Comment: thanks for response @Twocode.But it is not calling first line of function ie.

Comment: $('#proof_chzn').on('focus', function(e){alert"hello" }); at least what i want is alert should be called which is not happening.

Comment: @user762641 you are focus on the wrong target, set an id to the textbox and try it again http://jsfiddle.net/dyCKu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/animesh_sheolikar/SDRua/ .for this js and chosen plugin need to be loaded

Comment: for chosen jquery dropdown only creating problem .not or

Comment: $("#proof_chzn").live('focus', function(e){ alert("hi"); });

Comment: but it is shooting multiple times .ie no of options X that no of times